# How to get the data Using Yii2 Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii2-basic-app

What i am trying
I have 2 table staff and salarydetails,i want to fetch staff name and there respective salary

```
   $salaries = SalaryDetails::find()->select('salary_details.total_salary AS salary,staff.name AS name')
            ->leftJoin("staff",'salary_details.staff_id = staff.id');
        
            


                if ($fcreated_date != null && $tcreated_date != null) {
                    $salaries->andFilterWhere(['>=','salary_details.salary_given_date', $fcreated_date]);   
                    $salaries->andFilterWhere(['<=', 'salary_details.salary_given_date', $tcreated_date]);
                }
```

when i try to print sql raw query by using

```
echo $salaries->createCommand()->getRawsql();
```

i got SELECT `salary_details`.`total_salary` AS `salary`, `staff`.`name` AS `name` FROM `salary_details` LEFT JOIN `staff` ON salary_details.staff_id = staff.id
and this query gives the data i wanted in phpMyadmin

But the array gives ie, print_r($salaries); gives

yii\db\ActiveQuery Object ( [sql] => [on] => [joinWith] => [select] => Array ( [0] => salary_details.total_salary AS salary [1] => **staff.name AS name** ) [selectOption] => [distinct] => [from] => [groupBy] => [join] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => LEFT JOIN [1] => staff [2] => salary_details.staff_id = **staff.id** ) ) [having] => [union] => [params] => Array ( ) [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) [where] => [limit] => [offset] => [orderBy] => [indexBy] => [modelClass] => common\models\SalaryDetails [with] => [asArray] => [multiple] => [primaryModel] => [link] => [via] => [inverseOf] => )

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in your `print_r`, `$salaries` is an `ActiveQuery` instance. Call the methods `->asArray()->all()` on it to get the records.

```
$query = SalaryDetails::find()
    ->select('salary_details.total_salary AS salary,staff.name AS name')
    ->leftJoin("staff",'salary_details.staff_id = staff.id');
if ($fcreated_date != null && $tcreated_date != null) {
    $query->andFilterWhere(['>=','salary_details.salary_given_date', $fcreated_date]);   
    $query->andFilterWhere(['<=', 'salary_details.salary_given_date', $tcreated_date]);
}
$salaries = $query->asArray()->all();
```

Note that without `asArray` the `all` would return an array of `SalaryDetails` records and you would loss the staff name.